# Ordering products by product type in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, product

I've been asked by a client is it possible for them to be able to manually order product(Types) on the front-end instead of using the default A-Z option.

For example:

- Customer visits product listing page
- Selects product type from the filterable options E.G "t-shirts"
- Products show based on that query but are organised how they have defined possibly in the backend somewhere, or as a Shopify setting that I setup.

I can't seem to find anything from digging around on the internet and I can't think how I'd do this on my own but wondered if anyone else ha had experience or ideas for how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a collection with the condition "Product type is equal to your_type". Then after you save the collection you can choose to order the products manually (the default is alphabetically).

[image: Order products in collection manually]